# Best place for holding values in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi
I working on Asp .Net project(Web App).
I have to many values, properties and fields. In order to use them I need to save them in somewhere.(I know about Session, Application and Cookie).

`application` isn't good cuz it is same for all user's but session is better(I need these values in server-side). Also `cookie` isn't good and I won't use that for security problem.
`Session` is good but if I use session a lot I must pay for massive memory on `Host-Server`.

> So is there any better place can hold them ?

**Edit 1**
For more Information recently I fetch these values from database (so I won't to save them in database). and also use Wcf service for get these values from database. I want to hold these values to use them (for example sending them for service-method to do something or do  something visually in page). 
Thanks All

Comment: The best practice is very clear: It depends.

Comment: It does sound like you need a database which is also going to cost you more but will be more scalable in the future.

Comment: Your question is very general; try being specific.

Comment: Are you talking about permanent storage of these values or temporary caching?

Comment: biggest problem is session keep values until session will be expired.

Comment: There isn't a one-size-fits-all solution to State. Statement's like "..isn't good", "..is better" are meaningless without knowing the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been commented, there are many ways of implementing state management, depending on the amount of data your looking to persist, overall volume of traffic, hosting costs, maintainabilty, etc.

This [MS link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx) describes the pros and cons of some of the techniques.

Comment: Good article but dosen't help me

Comment: @Rev - then you need to explain your problem better.

Comment: @rev, another possibility is to retrieve the values from the db/WCF from each page, rather than "passing" the data from page to page. This will depend on how static your data is, and the relative performance of original process vs any state mgmt technique.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Session is the best way to use. Actually its consumes the comparatively least memory of all while using the server side state management technique.

If the values are much higher than you can use to store those values in database with the sessionid as the key with them. So that it will consume some what less memory from the server.

Answer (score 0):

A database could be a good idea.  Maybe SQL Server Express or SQL Server Compact Edition